# beautify my URL from database.getfilepath

Tags: xpages, ssjs

In my xpages app I want to redirect the user based upon a role. However the computed URL results in a ugly URL with %5C in the pathname

```
var baseURL = context.getUrl().toString().split(facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getRequestURI())[0];

var path =escape(database.getFilePath());

if (context.getUser().getRoles().contains("[Administrator]") || context.getUser().getRoles().contains("[SuperAdmin]") || context.getUser().getRoles().contains("[Ledamot]")){
    facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect(baseURL + slash + path + "/employees.xsp?sorting=asc")
}else{
    context.redirectToPage("index.xsp")
}
```

This results in something like: : https://server/directory%5cdatabase.nsf/employees.xsp?sorting=asc

Comment: It's because you are escaping the file path

Comment: http://blog.gollmick.de/mgoblog.nsf/dx/some-more-Functions-for-XPages-URLEncode-URLDecode.htm But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are redirecting to the same database, you can calculate the url prefix (host + database path) like this:

```
context.getUrl().toString().split(view.getPageName())[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

%5c is a backslash, so what you have to do is replace backslashes in the filepath with forward slashes. So something like this should work:

```
database.getFilePath().replace("\\", "/");
```